# Image array elements are zero outside the function

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an image into `Uint8Array` to use it in F5 steganography with the [`f5stego` package](https://github.com/desudesutalk/f5stegojs).

I tried to use the following code, but when I print `imageArray` in the console outside the function, it has 0 values, while inside it has the values representing the real image data.

```
var stegKey = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var stegger = new f5stego(stegKey); // init stegger with key

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), base64 = 'cover.jpg';
canvas.width = 43, canvas.height = 34;
var image = new Image();
var imageArray = new Uint8Array(4624);
image.onload = (function (canvas, ctx) {
    return function () {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 34, 34);
        // console.log(imageData.data);
        imageArray = imageData.data;
        console.log(imageArray);
    };
})(canvas, ctx);
image.src = base64;

console.log(imageArray);

// Data Array 
var message = "something secret ";
dataArray = new Uint8Array(message.length);
for (var i = 0, j = message.length; i < j; ++i) {
    dataArray[i] = message.charCodeAt(i);
}
console.log(dataArray);

//embed message into image
var secretImage = stegger.embed(imageArray, dataArray);
console.log(secretImage);

//extract message from image
var message = stegger.extract(secretImage);
console.log(message);
```

Comment: can you post the definition of f5stego? or at least link to it's public repository?

Comment: this is the link of f5stego:https://github.com/desudesutalk/f5stegojs

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is : when I try to print (imageArray) in console from outside the function it return zeros

Comment: The elements of (imageArray) outside the function have zeros values but inside the function have the real values which represent the imageData

Comment: Based on the information you provided I edited your question to better describe the problem. I don't have much experience with js, so If I have misrepresented it, feel fee to rollback or further edit it yourself.

Comment: Your console output is being reached before the `image.onload` event is completed. You need to wait until the image is loaded to do anything with it.

Comment: @MelanciaUK is correct

Comment: thanks a lot . i changed the code but i get either (bad image) or (image is too big) from executing of this line : var secretImage = stegger.embed(imageArray, dataArray);

Answer (score 1):

You are converting image to `Uint8Array` of pixels. But `f5stego.js` lib needs actual JPEG file bytes, not pixels.

If you working with JPEG file encoded in base64, you need some library which will convert this string into `Uint8Array`. For example, you can use [this code](https://gist.github.com/desudesutalk/37fa1be3354acdbf8fa61df12d5e7f04).

If you use base64 lib I linked to, your code should be something like this:

```js
var stegKey = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var stegger = new f5stego(stegKey); // init stegger with key

// just base64 encoded file without data URL scheme
var base64 = '/9j/4AA............6D/2Q==',
    imageArray;

// convert Base64 encoded file to Uint8Array
imageArray = b64.dec(base64)

console.log(imageArray);

// Data Array
var message = "something secret ";
dataArray = new Uint8Array(message.length);
for (var i = 0, j = message.length; i < j; ++i) {
    dataArray[i] = message.charCodeAt(i);
}
console.log(dataArray);

//embed message into image
var secretImage = stegger.embed(imageArray, dataArray);
console.log(secretImage);

//extract message from image
var message = stegger.extract(secretImage);
console.log(message);
```

And if you want to modify image using `canvas` and then use it with `f5stego.js` you need to use [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) function instead of `getImageData`. And here you again need to deal with Base64 encoding. In this case your code should be something like this:

```js
var stegKey = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    stegger = new f5stego(stegKey); // init stegger with key

// Data Array
var message = "something secret ",
    dataArray = new Uint8Array(message.length);
for (var i = 0, j = message.length; i < j; ++i) {
    dataArray[i] = message.charCodeAt(i);
}
console.log(dataArray);

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    // now we use data URL scheme instead of plain base64 string
    base64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA............6D/2Q==',
    image = new Image(),
    imageArray;

canvas.width = 43;
canvas.height = 34;

image.onload = (function (canvas, ctx) {
    return function () {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);

        // imageData is also in data URL scheme. We need to keep base64 part only
        imageData = imageData.split(',')[1];

        // convert Base64 encoded file to Uint8Array
        imageArray = b64.dec(imageData);

        console.log(imageArray);

        //embed message into image
        var secretImage = stegger.embed(imageArray, dataArray);
        console.log(secretImage);

        //extract message from image
        var message = stegger.extract(secretImage);
        console.log(message);
    };
})(canvas, ctx);

image.src = base64
```

Also note what capacity of f5 algorithm is something like 10% of original file size. That means what if you want to embed 1KB of data you need at least 10KB jpeg file.

Another hint: you use `charCodeAt` for converting string to `Uint8Array`. This will only work with ASCII characters and fail with UTF-8 symbols.